# Javascript/HTML won't enter switch case other than default

Tags: javascript, html

My task was to try and code the game of Pig. I am trying to have the code use a switch statement to determine which chunk of code to follow but it is skipping case 1 and case 2 and going directly to the default case. The `roll.score` is coming from this Javascript file:

```
function Dice(d1, d2){      //d1 = die 1   d2 = die 2
    this.d1 = d1?d1:parseInt(Math.random()*6 + 1);
    this.d2 = d2?d2:parseInt(Math.random()*6 + 1);
}

Dice.prototype.score = function(){         //d1 = die 1   d2 = die 2
    if(this.d1 == 1 || this.d2 == 1){
        return 1;   //return score 0 for turn
    }else if(this.d1 == 1 && this.d2 == 1){
        return 2;    //return 13 as code to reset score to 0 
    }else
        return parseInt(this.d1 + this.d2);
}

Dice.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "Rolled " + this.d1 + " and " + this.d2;
}
```

What it is supposed to do is return either 1, 2, or whatever the 2 number added together are. Like I mentioned above, no matter what the `roll.score()` returns, the switch statement always goes to the default case.

```
var again = true;
do {
    var roll = new Dice(parseInt(Math.random() * 6 + 1), parseInt(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
    window.alert(roll.toString());           
    turnCounter++;
    switch (roll.score) {
        case 1: // 1 die = 1
            playerScore = roll.score();
            again = false;
            rollCounter++;
            turnCounter++;
            document.write("Enters case 1");
            break;
        case 2: //2 = snake eyes       
            playerTotal = 0;
            playerScore = 0;
            again = false;
            rollCounter++;
            turnCounter++;
            break;
        default:
            playerScore += roll.score();
            rollCounter++;
            displayScore();
            document.write(roll.score() + "<br/>");
            var rollAgain = window.prompt("Do you want to roll again?(Y/N)");
            if (rollAgain.toUpperCase() === "N") {
                again = false;
                playerTotal += playerScore;
                displayScore();
                turnCounter++;
                if (playerScore > highScore)
                   highScore = playerScore;
            }
            break;
     }

     rollCounter++;
}while (again);
```

Comment: Exactlly! what's your mistake is that you are calling `roll.score` always as function not your functions logic values so your switch case always execute default part, where as it is a function so you can call it like this `switch (roll.score())` then it would return your expected value and might your issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch (roll.score) {` is not the same as `switch (roll.score()) {`

`roll.score` is a function, whereas you want to switch on the result on the returned result (`roll.score()`).